# Two things: Eclipse says "must be static" for EVERYTHING! and This method must return a result of type boolean, while it returns true

Tags: java, return-value, static-members

Heres my simple code for testing purposes.

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a != b) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> This method must return a result of type boolean

While at any given time it must either return true or false, and never returns both. Also,
no matter what I am doing, Eclipse tells me

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field bikeSpeed

for

```
void speedUp(){
    bikeSpeed++;
}
```

with `bikeSpeed` being

```
int bikeSpeed = 2;
```

Probably simple answer, but could anyone help? I know how to use booleans and such, and have never had a problem, but the simplest of things ^^^ is not working.

EDIT: Heres my speedUP:

```
void speedUp(){
    bikeSpeed++;
}
```

And heres my usage of it:

```
    System.out.println("Simple if && if-then-else testing.");
    if (isMoving == true) {
        System.err.println("You're already moving fast, no need to speed up!");
    } else {
        speedUp();
        System.out.println("Time to speed up!");
    }
```

EDIT AGAIN: The isMoving declaration and such is fine now, but the line 
        if (isMoving == true) {
gives the error: isMoving cannot be resolved to a variable. So does isMoving() if i switch it to that.
The last error is

speedUp();

gives: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method speedUp() from the type HelloWorld

EDIT lAST TIME: I hate this fix, since it doesnt seem correct to me, but eclipse seems to think that making EVERY SINGLE VARIABLE static fixes it (which it did) even though it wasnt used statically.

Comment: are you sure `speedUp()` is not declared static? are you sure the error showing is on `speedUp()`?

Comment: can you paste the whole class?

Comment: My code to speed up is.  

'code'
void speedUp(){
 bikeSpeed++;
 }
}
'/code'
and my usage of it is:
'code'

  if (isMoving == true) {
   System.err.println("You're already moving fast, no need to speed up!");
  } else {
   speedUp();
   System.out.println("Time to speed up!");
  } '/code'

Comment: @Java: Please edit that into the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a != b) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The compiler here is not detecting that one of those two branches **must** be hit, and therefore it thinks that there is a possible state where you would get to the end of the method without specifying a return value.  You can use `else` instead of `else if` or just `return a == b`.

That's not just a compiler deficiency; you could have a scenario where another thread is changing the values of `a` and `b` in the background, and depending on the timing both of those conditions might be false when they are evaluated.

Comment: or reduce it down to `boolean isMoving() { return a == b; }`

Comment: @Philipp: You were super fast with that comment; I added it like a minute after I posted :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent:

```
boolean isMoving(){
    return a == b;
}
```

Eclipse is complaining because it thinks that not all execution paths are handle. Try:

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a != b) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return //a is neither equal nor not equal to b???
    }
}
```

Note that the last branch can actually never happen because if `a == b` condition is not met than `a != b` *must* be true.

Comment: Actually, since `a` and `b` are not local, the second branch can in fact evaluate to false and thus be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

For this code:

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a != b) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How would the compiler reliably infer that your `if` statements are complementary? After all, couldn't another thread (in theory) possibly change the value of `a` or `b`? Then you might have a case where you aren't returning a value.

Simply provide an `else` (and in this case, use that instead of `else if`):

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also rely on the fact that the first `return` will prevent the rest of the code from executing:

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the first code snippet you can just do

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or even

```
boolean isMoving(){
    return a == b;
}
```

in your original code the java compiler cannot be sure any if condition is entered so it errors when it can't find a return at the end

you can also put a `assert false;` or `throw new RuntimeException();` at the end but this is unnecessary in this case

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code to

```
return a == b
```

but the reason it's complaining is that your code is equivalent to

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    } else if (a != b) {
        return false;
    } else {
        //oh no, nothing there!
    }
}
```

The static reference means that you're accessing a class field from somewhere you don't have an instance of the class. You could be accessing that field from your main method, which is static, without using an instance of the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

First problem is a bit annoying (but there is a reason for that - multythreading), java compiler sees that not all the bases are covered, the fix:

```
boolean isMoving(){
    if (a == b) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

in second you need to reference the object:

```
void speedUp(){
    this.bikeSpeed++;
}
```

Edit: 
Added multithreading info.

Looks the static problems that you have are in the main block of the code, since main method is static you can't reference object variables, you need to create instance of the object first and then reference the variables of that object.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that all the bases are covered once you introduce the possibility of multithreading. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, there's a case where the compiler can't tell you'll never get to the end of the block.
Alternatively you could just put a return false; before the closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, change your code as follows:

```
return a == b;
```

For your second problem, is there a name clash in your code? If you use:

```
void speedUp(){
    this.bikeSpeed++;
}
```

instead, does it fixes your problem? If yes, then you have two variables with the same name, which you should not be doing.